# VB.Net variable declaration : type or not to type?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In VB.Net, the usual way to declare a string would be :

```
Dim helloWorld As String = "Hello, World!"
```

However, you can also use dynamic variables, such as :

```
Dim helloWorld = "Hello, World!"
```

Both would end up to be the same thing, but what would be the best practice?

Comment: In your example, there's no difference

Comment: @the_lotus whether or not there's a difference depends on what `Option` is specified for the project/file. With `Option Infer`, that's a `String`. With `Option Strict`, that's a compiler error. With neither, that's an `Object`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Just tried option strick and there's no error

Comment: @the_lotus Make sure you turn it on: `Option Strict On` and explicitly turn `Option Infer Off`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ah! yes

Comment: @the_lotus Also, going back to read recent docs, they may have made the compiler a hair smarter about still inferring variable types in the last version or two of VB, such that it might still know that's a string with the assignment is on the same line as the declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Use a Type!

Really. VB sits on top of .Net, and .Net works best when you stick with explicit types. The only exceptions are with `Option Infer` turned on (it is now by default) and you also declare variables similar to C#'s `var`, or if you're doing COM interop or something else that truly requires a dynamic type... and that it is *exceedingly* rare.

Answer (score 9):

Answering to your question `what would be the best practice?`

Of course the best practice is declaring the object as the type that it would be.

If you don't do that then your code can have negative impact and influence about syntax errors or for example in IntelliSense, where sometimes could not show the object methods then neither you can't use them (if first you don't cast the object to the type which you really want) 'cause you don't set before the type when declaring.

An not the best example but just an example would be:

Suppose that you want to declare an Array, and you do it like this:

```
Dim myArray = {"qwerty"}
```

But it is not recognized as an Array, so methods are different (well, not at all in this example) from Array methods:

[image]

But if you do this:

```
 Dim myArray As Array = {"qwerty"}
```

[image]

So for the first case, you later would need to convert the type to the desired type you've really wanted to use it right:

[image]

And that's valid for other many examples where the type is confusing, like I've said is not the best example but I shown you a basic.

PS: Forgive my English.

Answer (score 3):

### Please...

It's safer to put the type and easier on the eye when you look at the code but I guess some people use it since it's still a feature after so many versions.

### Awww...Vb

It's VB. There is no difference. The compiler let's you do all kind of stuff and that is one of them.
You can also change some settings in your `vbproj` that will allow you to compile without a return in a function that should return something.

It will also let you use the keyword `ByVal` when you pass a reference type parameter which is very non-intuitive when you look at the code.

But still.. No, there is no difference in your example.

Comment: I think the exact opposite... If you hide the types, you might find better names :P But I guess it's just preference, right?

Comment: Better names ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: yeah sure. `int days` vs `var numberOfDaysElapsed` for example. Focusing more on the "what" instead of the implementation ("how")

Comment: Plus, using var (or any type of type inference) gets you the most generic types I think, so why not use it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project.

If it is a big project with a lot of lines and classes. Then you should type all the variables, since it will be easier to remember what you want to "said" when you programmed it.

Anyway, type variables in never a bad costume if you know that you will use it a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

This dynamic variable declaration was made for compatibility with older office libraries and such, or to be more convenient when returning some complex data type from a linq query. It wasn't done to replace primitives.

Answer (score 0):

If it is obvious for the any reader which type we have or noone cares, then typing out the type adds value for noone.

If we are uncertain if everyone with reasonable knowledge would decode which type a variable has and someone would actually care about it, it is important to specify the type explicitely or we act carelessly.

I like short formats and I hover a variable when I need to, but I understand that not everyone has my preference.

(Using the same policy everywhere for no other reason than that you want to use the same policy everywhere is dogmatic).